# I'm writing a SL4A script in QPython to mark unread SMS of inbox as read. and this is not working in Marshmallow

Tags: android, python-2.7, android-6.0-marshmallow, sl4a, qpython

I want to write an SL4A script to mark Unread SMS of inbox as Read. I want to run this script in QPython android application.

```
​import androidhelper as android
droid = android.Android()
ids = droid.smsGetMessageIds(True).result
print type(ids)
print ids
number = droid.smsMarkMessageRead(ids, True).result
print number
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTemX.jpg)
This is same as above.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuIaC.jpg)

Comment: What's the output you expected to get? For now, the question is really unclear. Does it work on other android versions?

Comment: I want 9 as the value of number variable.
and I've not tested in other Android versions.

Comment: I tested it now on android5 (`linux-armv7l`) with QPython3 (python version 3.2.2) and I also get zero as value of `number`. So this seems to be not android / qpython / python version related

Comment: Hey **Aemyl**,
It may not be a version related issue. But that is not the concern even.
I ultimately want a script which can _Mark unread SMS as Read_.

Comment: yes, I tried to figure out what the problem with your code is and I only figured out what is _not_ the problem. But I wanted you to know that. When you know more, it's more likely you can fix it one day ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google maybe has disabled general application being granted WRITE_SMS permission in newer android system (maybe >= M) , so the smsMarkMessageRead may not work.

I answered on https://www.facebook.com/groups/qpython/permalink/1410128472397009/

Just read the post's comments.